# Two languages, one view, different url path

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django project with two languages. What I want to achieve is to have different url path depend on current language. 
Not very nice but working solution is:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url("strefa-klienta/", views.client_zone, name="strefa_klienta"),
    url("client-zone/", views.client_zone, name="client-zone"),
    ...
]
```

**vievs.py**

```
def client_zone(request):
    return render(request, "client_zone.html")
```

**template.html**

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

{% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'pl-PL' %}
    <a href="{% url 'strefa_klienta' %}">{% trans 'Client zone' %}</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'client_zone' %}">{% trans 'Client zone' %}</a>
{% endif %}
```

The result is ok, I got urls:

- `domain.com/strefa-kleinta/` - for Polish language
- `domain.com/client-zone/` - for rest languages

which renders same view, but... It's not flexible. Maybe you can help and suggest a little more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Django's path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) for this purpose. You should use a custom regex path converter for this purpose. It will match any of the matching strings of a single URL and you can access what string was used using `kwargs` in a view.

Change your urls.py to a regular expression path to match the pattern with your strings:

```
from django.urls import re_path # Use re_path for Django > 2 else path

urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^(?P<lang_code>strefa-klienta|client-zone)/$', views.client_zone, name="client_zone_view"),
]
```

To get which language was used in your views.py, check `kwargs`

```
def client_zone(request, *args, **kwargs):
    lang_code = kwargs.get('lang_code')
    # You can send the lang_code in context in case you need it in template
    return render(request, "client_zone.html", context={'lang_code':lang_code})
```

Comment: So simple :) 
Thanks!!